# Result bind with different types?

Tags: f#

I've made a simple Computation Expression workflow for dealing with Results.

```
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Result =

    type Builder() =

        member __.Bind(x, f) = x |> Result.bind f

        member __.Return(x) = x

        member __.ReturnFrom(x) = Ok x

    let workflow = Builder()
```

I also use different types to represent different kids of errors:

```
type ValidationError<'a> = { Obj:'a; Message:string }
type InvalidOperationError = { Operation:string; Message:string }
```

The problem arises when two results have different error types.

```
LetterString.create : string -> Result<LetterString, ValidationError<string>>
Username.create : string -> Result<Username, ValidationError<string>>
PositiveDecimal.create : decimal -> Result<PositiveDecimal, ValidationError<decimal>>
```

```
let user = 
    Result.workflow {
        let! name = LetterString.create "Tom"
        let! username = Username.create "Tom01098"
        // Error occurs here.
        let! balance = PositiveDecimal.create 100m

        return! { 
            // User record creation elided.
        }
    }
```

```
FS0001  Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'Result<PositiveDecimal,ValidationError<string>>'    
but given a
    'Result<PositiveDecimal,ValidationError<decimal>>'
```

I have already tried using a DU type of all errors:

```
type Error<'a> =
    | ValidationError of Obj:'a * Message:string
    | InvalidOperationError of Operation:string * Message:string
```

This has a similar problem when the generic parameter `'a` is different between errors. It also loses the exact type of error in the type signature of the function.

The expected result is that the entire workflow has a unified error type, preferably as specific as possible in terms of type.

Comment: Could you add the rest of your code to the question? Where does the error occur?

Comment: I've beefed up the code example. The problem is that because `let!` is a call to `Result.bind` behind the scenes it does not work as the error types are different.

Comment: I think the relevant question here is: why do you need this `'a` value? What does your error handling code do with it? Depending on the answer, you might get away with storing it as `obj`, or not at all.

Comment: Make your validation error the same in all cases. Usually this is just a string, i.e., the creation functions (which really know best what went wrong, after all) will format a string containing the error message, ready to show the user and/or log.

Comment: I suppose this is best - the reasoning for the `'a` is for formatting the string later, but that hardly makes any sense when I could just format it right away! My main focus for this was to make it apparent in the function signature what the error could be caused by, but I guess a single DU will have to do :( Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be solved by removing the generic parameter and using a single `Error` DU. Unfortunately this loses the signature I wanted, but it will have to do.